Flash message view component rendering :type as a :message?
I have followed this post https://reinteractive.com/articles/how-to-create-flash-messages-in-Rails-7 to add nice flash messages with tailwind, which got me into View Components. Everything works apart from  the :type.
If I add a flash message like the example says:
def home
  flash[:message] = "Welcome to the home page!"
  flash[:type] = :notice
end

It displays:
screenshot of flash messages
This is the component.html.erb:
<div class='relative flex px-4 py-3 space-x-2 border <%= color_classes %>' role='alert'>
  <strong class='font-bold'><%= message %></strong>
  <span class='pl-5'>
  <%= heroicon 'x-mark', options: { 'data-action': 'click->flash-message#close', class: 'w-6 h-6 fill-current', role: 'button' } %>
  </span>
</div>

This is what is rendered:
<div data-controller="flash-message" class="inset-0 p-6 items-start justify-end">
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
    <div class="relative flex px-4 py-3 space-x-2 border bg-gray-100 border-gray-400 text-gray-700" role="alert">
      <strong class="font-bold">Welcome to the home page!</strong>

 <div class="relative flex px-4 py-3 space-x-2 border bg-gray-100 border-gray-400 text-gray-700" role="alert">
  <strong class="font-bold">notice</strong>

Is there an error in the post or has something been updated in the past couple of months?

On a side note  besides the guide being broken I kind of hate this approach. The color_classes method hides your styling in a private method in a view component. Just define CSS rules for the standard log classes in your stylesheets .flash.success { ... }, .flash.warning { ... } and separate the concerns. I'm pretty sure future maintainers will thank you for not having to pull the whole thing appart to find out where to change the font color. Just because you're using CSS  framework X doesn't mean you have to let your app succomb to classitis.

Thank you, I have decided to rebuild my app using RSpec, Tailwind  & View Components so when I saw this post I thought perfect, be a good introduction to try out view components! I sent an email to the creators of the post and they are saying it is working on their machine.

This makes no sense:
flash[:message] = "Welcome to the home page!"
flash[:type] = :notice

it should be:
flash[:notice] = "Welcome to the home page!"

If you inspect flash you can see what you're iterating over:
#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x00007f9ede9208b8
 @discard=#<Set: {}>,
 @flashes={"notice"=>"Welcome to the home page!"},    # <= this
 @now=nil>

<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  #               │     └─ "Welcome to the home page!"   
  #               └─ "notice"   
  <%= render FlashMessage::Component.new(type: type, message: message) %>
<% end %>


EDIT:
I could not get this to work so I reverted back to the orginal code using a partial for flash messages.
app/views/shared/_flash_message.html.erb
<% flash.each do |key, message| %>
<div data-controller='flash-message' class='inset-0 p-6 items-start 
justify-end'>
  <div class='flex flex-col items-center justify-center'>
    <div class='relative flex px-4 py-3 space-x-2 border <%= 
    flash_class(key) %>' role='alert'>
      <strong class='font-bold'><%= message %></strong>
      <span class='pl-5'>
        <%= heroicon 'x-mark', options: { 'data-action': 'click->flash- 
        message#close', class: 'w-6 h-6 fill-current', role: 'button' } %>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>

app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def flash_class(key)
    flash_class = {
      "success" => "bg-green-100 border-green-400 text-green-700",
      "error" => "bg-red-100 border-red-400 text-red-700",
      "notice" => "bg-blue-100 border-blue-400 text-blue-700",
      "warning" => "bg-yellow-100 border-yellow-400 text-yellow-700"}
      
    flash_class[key]
  end 

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= render 'shared/flash_message' %>

